# Retrieve Check box from array they stored in

Tags: jquery, html

i have this function and i want to create another function to retrieve the check box array (USER_CARD_DECLARE_DATA_List) on the model again

```
userobj.SaveDeclarationForm = function ()
{
    var USER_CARD_DECLARE_DATA_List = []
    $(".option").map(function () {
        var USER_CARD_DECLARE_DATA = {}
        if ($(this).find(".RESULT_VAL")[0].checked == true) {
            USER_CARD_DECLARE_DATA.RESULT_VAL = 1;
        }
        else {
            USER_CARD_DECLARE_DATA.RESULT_VAL = 0;
        }
        USER_CARD_DECLARE_DATA_List.push(USER_CARD_DECLARE_DATA);
    })
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    userobj.declaration = USER_CARD_DECLARE_DATA_List;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var USER_CARD_DECLARE_DATA_List = []
```

to:

```
var USER_CARD_DECLARE_DATA_List = this.USER_CARD_DECLARE_DATA_List = []
```

Now you can access the array in other methods of `userobj` with:

```
this.USER_CARD_DECLARE_DATA_List
```